# RegEx - Require minimum length of one group

Tags: regex

I'm trying to make a nickname validator. Here are the rules I want:

> - Total character count must be between 3 and 15
> - There can be two non-consecutive spaces
> - Only letters (a-z) are allowed
> - Each word separated by a space can begin with an uppercase letter, the rest of the word must be lowercase
> - At least one of the words must have 3 or more characters

This is what I currently have which checks the four first rules, but I have no idea how to check the last rule.

```
^(?=.{3,15}$)(\b[A-Z]?[a-z]* ?\b){1,3}$
```

Should match:

- Yaw
- yaw
- James Bond
- Monkey D Luffy
- List item

Shouldn't match:

- YaW
- `Two  spaces` (with two consecutive space characters)
- No no no
- JamesBond

Comment: why `Two spaces` cannot match?

Comment: Because it has two spaces between "Two" and "spaces" (a fact that doesn't show up with this formatting)

Comment: Thanks @L.ScottJohnson, I realized it after adding the comment :)

Comment: Yeah, I've edited the question to format it so it shows up (and with a comment so it can't be missed).

Comment: Is it for PHP? Do you need Unicode support?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Regex: `^(?=[A-Za-z ]{3,15}$)(?=[A-Za-z ]*[A-Za-z]{3})(?:\b[A-Z]?[a-z]*\ ?\b){1,3}$`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/OhliNs/3)

For the last rule, a positive lookahead without space was used `(?=[A-Za-z ]*[A-Za-z]{3})`

Comment: That's really great. Why have you split the words check in two? One with the space and another one without it? I've tried deleting the last group and changing {1,2} to {1,3} and aparently it's the same because the \b wouldn't allow you to end with a space.

Comment: @YaW, you are right, that is not necessary. feel free to edit the answer that worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

> but I have no idea how to check the **last rule**

As you only allow `[A-Za-z]` and space in your regex, you could simply use `(?=.*?\S{3})` which [looks ahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for 3 [non white-space](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html#negated) characters. `.*?` matches [lazily](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#lazy_solution) any amount of any characters.

As soon as 3 *non white-space* characters are required the initial lookahead can be improved to the negative `^(?!.{16})` as the minimum of 3 is already required in `\S{3}` ⇒ `[A-Za-z][a-z]*`

Further you can drop the initial `\b` which is redundant as there can only be start or space before.

```
^(?!.{16})(?=.*?\S{3})(?:[A-Za-z][a-z]* ?\b){1,3}$
```

[Here is a demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/0JiNG1/2) (for more regex info see the [SO regex faq](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/5527985))

If your tool supports [atomic groups](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#atomic), improve performance by use of [`(?>` instead of `(?:`](https://regex101.com/r/0JiNG1/3)